# Regarding the Gmail Id usage in C2DM server in android?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In my app ,im using push notifications and for that i am planning to use android C2DM.

But i googled several times and bit more confused in setting gmail account for this.

Below are the steps which i followed

step1: Sign up Google C2DM server with a mail id like "mynewapp@gmail.com"

After this,when i tried to implement  it in android,some confusing arises,ie

```
 Intent rI = new Intent ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
 rI.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
 rI.putExtra("sender", "Gmail Id");
 this.startService(rI);
```

In this

```
  rI.putExtra("sender", "Gmail Id");
```

Actually which gmail id i have to use?Is that which i registered in C2DM server or users gmail id (using accounts from device).

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not user's ID , That is the 
G mail id which you have used to Registered for the C2DM server

Means it is Sender's G mail ID